# How to make a custom column with same properties as timestamp() columns?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I need a third column ( **sorting_date** ) with the same properties as the **created_at** and **updated_at** columns, they are both generated with **timestamp()**.

I tried to do this in my migrations:

```
$table->datetime('sorting_date')->default(Carbon::now());
```

But that leaves me with a naked string of the date/time and hence I can't call all the goodie methods that exists for the two others eg. `->format('Y-m')`

How can I add column **'sorting_date'** and let it be an instance of the same class as **created_at** and **updated_at**?

### Update

@PuriaDeveloper helped me with getting the column time to this:

```
$table->timestamp('sorting_date')->nullable()->default(Carbon::now());
```

But I still can't access the handy goodies attached to the carbon class.. Please see below my cut-outs from tinker:

```
>>>$i->sorting_date
=> "2019-01-25 11:09:57"
>>> $i->created_at
=> Illuminate\Support\Carbon @1548414597 {#3043
     date: 2019-01-25 11:09:57.0 UTC (+00:00),
   }
>>>
```

I need my column to produce the date wrapped in a carbon-collection! How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add 'sorting_date' to $dates property of your model like this

```
class YourModel extends Model
{
    protected $dates = [
        'sorting_date',
   ];
}
```

For more details, check the docs here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
$table->timestamp('sorting_date');
```

for more infomation check this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#columns);

Comment: hmm.. this seems to be in the right direction but I still only get a naked string when adding the time with Carbon::now()

Comment: try this :  Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();

Comment: nope, sorry same string. I'll make an update of the question!